# Why doesn't jQuery work on a WordPress page?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am working on my [website](https://menacetopests.com/). jQuery does not work on the WordPress page. Here is my code:

```
<script>
  color = $("#colorPicker").val()
</script>
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

I'm using the Header and Footer Scripts Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress jQuery installations use the `jQuery` keyword instead of `$`. Change your code to this:

```
<script>
  color = jQuery("#colorPicker").val();
</script>
```

Alternatively, use the document.ready event handler and alias the jQuery instance passed in the argument to the function:

```
<script>
  jQuery($ => {
    color = $("#colorPicker").val();
  });
</script>
```